# ruby regex: match URL recurring pattern

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to be able to match all the following cases below using Ruby 1.8.7.

```
/pages/multiedit/16801,16809,16817,16825,16833
/pages/multiedit/16801,16809,16817
/pages/multiedit/16801
/pages/multiedit/1,3,5,7,8,9,10,46
```

I currently have:

```
\/pages\/multiedit\/\d*
```

This matches upto the first set of numbers. So for example:

```rb
"/pages/multiedit/16801,16809,16817,16825,16833"[/\/pages\/multiedit\/\d*/]
# => "/pages/multiedit/16801"
```

See http://rubular.com/r/ruFPx5yIAF for example.

Thanks for the help, regex gods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use:

```
/\/pages\/multiedit\/[\d,]+/
```

Here's a demonstration of the pattern at http://rubular.com/r/h7VLZS1W1q

`[\d,]+` means "find one or more numbers or commas"

The reason `\d*` doesn't work is it means "find zero or more numbers". As soon as the pattern search runs into a comma it stops. You have to tell the engine that it's OK to find numbers *and* commas.

Answer (score 2):

```
\/pages\/multiedit\/\d+(?:,\d+)*
```

Example: http://rubular.com/r/0nhpgki6Gy

**Edit**: Updated to not capture anything... Although the performance hit would be negligible. (Thanks Tin Man)

The currently accepted answer of

```
\/pages\/multiedit\/[\d,]+
```

may not be a good idea because that will also match the following strings

```
.../pages/multiedit/,,,
.../pages/multiedit/,1,
```

My answer requires there be at least one digit before the first comma, and at least one digit between commas, and it must end with a digit.

Comment: Be careful using `(...)` in patterns because they're capturing. Instead you should use `(?:...)` which is non-capturing.